# Get a parameter from a route?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have the following route:

```
Route::get('news', [
    'as' => 'news',
    'uses' => 'ArticleController@getIndex',
]);
```

There are also other routes that use the same resource controller, e.g:

```
Route::get('travel', [
    'as' => 'travel',
    'uses' => 'ArticleController@getIndex',
]);
```

In the article controller, how can I get the category of the articles. e.g. travel or news?

I can't turn it into a route param e.g.

```
Route::get('{travel}', [
    'as' => 'travel',
    'uses' => 'ArticleController@getIndex',
]);
```

As there are other sections such as contact, faqs, etc that do not use the article controller.

I know I could put it all on one route:

```
Route::get('/article/{category}', [
    'as' => 'travel',
    'uses' => 'ArticleController@getIndex',
]);
```

But I want pretty URLS like:

```
mydomain.com/category-slug/article-slug
```

Ideally if I could use a resource controller:

```
Route::resource('news', ArticleController');
```

With some sort of array:

```
Route::resource(['news', 'travel'], ArticleController');
```

So my questions:

1. How can I get the name of the resource. e.g. news, travel in my controller?
2. Is there an easy way to specify varying routes to the same resource?

Comment: put your routes which are static above the dynamic route

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Example Keep your routes like this as your static routes will be limited and need to be unique so they will not get conflict between routes
**demo routes :**

```
Route::get('contact', [
    'as' => 'contact',
    'uses' => 'contactController@getIndex',
]);

Route::get('{travel}', [
    'as' => 'travel',
    'uses' => 'ArticleController@getIndex',
]);
```

Comment: This will not work out, the getIndex function will not be able to distinguish between the two routes. Except with further route checks

Comment: @MinaAbadir i have just gave the idea, not specific about the functions name, just keeping the dynamic route at last was my intention

Comment: I understand your point of view. I am just pointing out an issue with the answer.

Comment: No I think this will work.  The first getIndex function is being called on the `ContactController`.  The second one will then be able to distinguish between news/travel because it gets passed in.

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve a route like that:

```
mydomain.com/category-slug/article-slug
```

Use the following:

```
Route::get('/{category}/{article}', 'ArticleController@getArticle');
```

Then in your controller, you will have 2 parameters in your `getArticle` method.

```
public function getArticle($category, $article)
{
    //Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to have pretty urls you need to make a few steps:

**1)** 
First of all you need to add a column to your articles table called for example 'slug'.

**2)** Then you need to specify your route key in your article model. Like this:

**Article model**

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

**3)** When you add an article you should create the slug by your own in order to be unique. so in your controller that you create the article add this code.

```
$slug = str_slug($article['title'], '-');
$slugs_count = DB::table('articles')->where('name',$article['title'])-  >count();
if($slugs_count>1){
    $slug = $slug.'-'.($slugs_count-1);
}
$article->slug = $slug;
$article->update();
```

**4)** Now we have to set the route

```
Route::get('/article/{slug}', [
    'as'   => 'travel',
    'uses' => 'ArticleController@getIndex'
])->where(['slug','[\w\d\-\_]+']);
```

**5)** Finally in order to get the article you need

```
$article = Article::where('slug','=',$slug)->first();
```

If you want to use categories etc you could pass more parameters in your route and manipulate it in your controller. like this

```
Route::get('/article/{category}/{slug}', [
    'as'   => 'travel',
    'uses' => 'ArticleController@getIndex'
])->where(['slug','[\w\d\-\_]+','category','[\w\d\-\_]+']);
```

The where clause is to restrict the parameter with some regular expressions(its optional).
I forgot to mention that the routekeyname in your model works in laravel 5.2.